# Setar valor do $scope de um Controller a partir de uma Directive Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directives, angularjs-scope

Estou tentando fazer com que a partir de um evento em uma Directive, seja chamado um método pertencente a um Controller, a chamada do método do Controller já está correta, só que parece que o `$scope`, dentro desse método está errado, pois se seto o `$scope.file.data` a partir da chamado do evento da Directive ele até seta o valor, mas não atualiza a `View`, já se seto o `$scope.file.data` a partir do evento do `ng-click` na `div` do Controller, tudo ocorre como o esperado.

O que estou tentando é o seguinte:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.file = {
    data: "nada!"
  };
  $scope.setExternal = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $scope.file.data = data;
  };
});

app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      setOnClick: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.on("click", function() {
        scope.setOnClick({
          param: "Clicou na directive!"
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.box {
  padding: 25px 0px;
  border: 2px dashed #bbb;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font: 20pt bold'Vollkorn';
  color: #bbb;
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    {{file.data}}

    <div class="box" ng-click="setExternal('Clicou na div!')">
      Está é uma Div do controller. Clique aqui!
    </div>
    <div class="box" my-directive set-on-click="setExternal(param)">
      Está é a Directive. Clique aqui!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Exemplo também no jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/eLj3u7ov/4/)

O que posso está deixando de fazer para que a chamada a partir da Directive:

```
element.on("click", function() {
    scope.setOnClick({
        param : "Clicou na directive!"
    });
});
```

tenha um `$scope` válido como o `ng-click` da `div`?

> Obs: no meu caso real o evento na Directive não é um simples `click`, e sim um processo um pouco mais complexo. Utilizei um exemplo com click para fins didáticos e práticos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta adicionar `scope.$apply();`:

```
element.on("click", function() {
    scope.setOnClick({
        param : "Clicou na directive!"
    });
    scope.$apply();
});
```

[Fiddle atualizado](http://jsfiddle.net/eLj3u7ov/5/)

Dica: utilize `$scope` apenas para passagem de dados entre `directives`. No Angular 2, `$scope` será completamente modificado pois muitos desenvolvedores usam `$scope` para tudo, e acabam criando problemas que não existiriam se utilizassem os `controllers` corretamente (lembre-se que `directive`'s possuem `controllers`).

Outra vantagem, é ser muito mais difícil ocorrerem conflitos de nomes e prover melhor re-usabilidade de código.

Comment: Uhm, então o scope, está certo? O que acontece é que ele não está aplicando as alterações no View e o `$apply()` faz isso. Certo? Interessante mas estranho =(. E a respeito da dica: como não conheço muito bem angular, não entendi se o que estou fazendo está correto, ou está errado, partindo de sua dica? Parece-me está correto, pois estou utilizando `$scope` apenas para passagem de dados.

Comment: Sim, faltou apenas o `$apply`. Por alguma razão o Angular não fazendo o dirty check. Utilizando `$apply`, a gente força isso. Note que o Angular não permite chamadas aninhadas a `$apply` e que o próprio Angular utiliza `$apply` para realizar o dirty check. Sobre o uso do `$scope`, na sua diretriz esta correto, mas no seu controller, o correto seria utilizar `this.file = ...` e `this.setExternal = ...`, por exemplo. É necessário alterar as chamadas na sua view, para que funcione, e é necessário dar um apelido ao controller (`ng-controller='myController as apelido'`).

Comment: Não se preocupe, a doc do Angular não é muito clara com relação a isso. Na versão 2, estão deixando explícito o modo se deve utilizar `$scope`, inclusive com a possibilidade de deixar de existir e ser manipulada automaticamente pelo Angular (a versão 2 ainda não foi se quer definida completamente sua arquitetura, mas não será nem um pouco compatível com a versão 1).